# Cannot access through model from the model that defines m2m field

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am trying to build a simple e-commerce website with django 2.2.4 . I have `Product` and `Cart` models connected with through model `Quantity` as shown below

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description     = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    mrp             = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.0)
    final_price     = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.0)
    discount        = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.0)


class Cart(models.Model):
    user            = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    products        = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True, through='Cart.Quantity')
    total_price     = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, default=0.00, max_digits=10)
    

class Quantity(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart    = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    val     = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
```

Now in my `views.py` I want to to access quantities for each product in my cart.

```
def home(request):
    cart_obj, is_new = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request) # my custom method to create new object
    print(cart_obj.quantity_set) # prints Cart.Quantity.None
    print(cart_obj.products.all()) # prints QuerySet of products in this cart
    return render(request, 'Cart/home.html',{"cart":cart_obj})
```

I am new to django. I don't know why i can't access quantity from cart object.

**Interesting thing i noticed** that in python shell when i run same command

```
>>> from Cart.models import Cart, Quantity
>>> c1 = Cart.objects.first()
>>> c1.quantity_set.all()
<QuerySet [<Quantity: Quantity object (1)>]>
```

Why am i unable to access something in my `views.py` while i access same thing in my python shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cart_obj.quantity_set` is a *manager*, not a queryset, and this will, both in your shell and in the view print `Cart.Quanty.None`.

If you add [**`.all()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#all) however, it will turn it into a queryset and print the elements, so you should use:

```
print(cart_obj.quantity_set.all())
#                            ^ use .all()
```

If you drop the `.all()` in your shell, it will also print `Cart.Quantity.None`, so this has nothing to do with the view versus the shell. Both do exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very stupid of me. I got confuse by seeing `Cart.Quantity.None` in the first place. So I thought `.all()` will give me error and never tried doing it.